# Query to produce survey summary (PIVOT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Let's suppose I have two tables:

```
Question (Id, Text)
Answer (Value, QuestionId, Guid)
```

Column `Guid` groups answers from the same person.

I need a query to produce results like this:

```
'Question 1' | 'Question 2'
4            | 3
1            | NULL
NULL         | 5
2            | 6
9            | NULL
```

Questions texts are transformed into column headers and answers values are in rows. Answers are grouped by `Guid`, so there are answers from one person in one row. If a person didn't answer particular question, NULL is returned.

Number of questions can vary.

Data used to produce sample results:

```
 Question
 Id   | Text
 1    | Question 1
 2    | Question 2

 Answer
 Value | QuestionId | Guid
 4     | 1          | AAA
 3     | 2          | AAA
 1     | 1          | BBB
 5     | 2          | CCC
 2     | 1          | DDD
 6     | 2          | DDD
 9     | 1          | EEE
```

Can you please help me out with a query to produce the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an unknown number of questions then tou will need to use dynamic SQL to `PIVOT` this:

```
DECLARE @colsFinal AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsFinal = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME(Id) 
                           + ' as Question_'+ cast(Id as varchar(10))
                    from question
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME(Id) 
                    from question
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colsFinal + ' from 
             (
                select questionid, value, guid
                from question q
                left join value v
                  on q.id = v.questionid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(value)
                for questionid in (' + @colsPivot + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf1c3/2)

If you had a known number of columns, then you could hard-code the values for the `PIVOT` (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf1c3/6)):

```
select [1] as Question1, [2] as Question2
from 
(
  select questionid, value, guid
  from question q
  left join value v
    on q.id = v.questionid
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for questionid in ([1], [2])
) p
```

Or you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf1c3/9)):

```
select max(case when q.id = 1 then v.value end) Question1,
  max(case when q.id = 2 then v.value end) Question2
from question q
left join value v
  on q.id = v.questionid
group by guid
```

Comment: Well, this is crazy.. How did you manage to write all that stuff so fast? :)

Comment: The first SQL Fiddle example does exactly what I need, thank you! However, I do not get one thing.. How does grouping by Guid works in your query? I cannot see anything related to that.

Comment: @jakubka in the last query it works because it then produces all rows. If you remove the `GROUP BY Guid` you will only get one result.  The same thing will happen it you exclude `GUID` from the `SELECT` statement only one row will appear. You need to make the values distinct since there is an aggregate function and the `GUID` does that. :)

Comment: I get it now! Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wish to hard code the Question Numbers, then you're limited to using dynamic SQL to build up the question list.

[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

For specific questions, if you know their texts, see sample below

```
create table Question(id int, text varchar(100));
insert Question select 1, 'Question 1'
union all select 2, 'The 2nd';
create table Answer(
  value int,
  questionid int,
  guid varchar(10));
insert Answer select
 4     , 1          , 'AAA' union all select
 3     , 2          , 'AAA' union all select
 1     , 1          , 'BBB' union all select
 5     , 2          , 'CCC' union all select
 2     , 1          , 'DDD' union all select
 6     , 2          , 'DDD' union all select
 9     , 1          , 'EEE';
GO
select guid, [Question 1], [The 2nd]
from (
    select guid, text, value
    from Answer A
    join Question Q on A.questionid=q.id) p
pivot (max(value) for text in ([Question 1], [The 2nd])) v
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize I can use a harmless function like max to get a single value. :) Still, number of questions is completely unknown, so I am stuck with dynamic SQL I am afraid.. Thank you anyway!